# how do I display(or call) the contents of an anonymous function that is defined inside of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, p5.js

I want to call `ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 5)` in the location where I specified it to do so (`Array[0]`) When I `console.log(Array[0])` it shows the function inside of the array but it does not call the function when I specify the array's index.

```
function translate1()  {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var Array = [
    function() {ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 5)}
  ];
console.log(Array[0]); // displays as expected here

Array[0]; // I want the function to be called here
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20);
Array[0]; // and again here
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20);
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 5);
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20);
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 5);
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20);
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 5);
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the function using `()`

```
Array[0]()
```

Since the function doesn't have a `return` there isn't much benefit in doing `console.log(Array[0]())` which would display `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be stored in arrays. For example we can store a function to say hello in an array:

```
var arr = [function(){return "hello";}];
```

now we have a function stored in arr[0] and

```
console.log(arr[0]);
```

displays something like function...

To call a function we use the call operator ()

```
console.log(arr[0]());
```

displays: hello

Keep in mind that Array is the name of a constructor... the constructor to create an array, so it is best not to reuse it as the name of an array.

Here is a code snippet that is similar to the code in your question.

```js
function draw()  {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let arr = [
    function() {ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 25, 50)}
  ];
  console.log(arr[0]); // log out the function
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  arr[0](); // call or execute the function
  ctx.stroke();
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" height='100' width='100'></canvas>
```